# Scaling d3's histogram x domain causes "Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute" errors

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, histogram

I'm trying to display a histogram using D3.

I started with the [official example here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/3048450/) and tried to change the scale of the x domain.

However, if I change the scale of the x domain, I get errors on the width of the individual histogram buckets.

The code in the example works ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tn9yxhbj/)):

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 1])
  .range([0, width]);
```

But this does not ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4374h66/)):

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0.2, 1])
  .range([0, width]);
```

Others have mentioned that, in order to zoom the x axis, you should use this:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data))
  .range([0, width]);
```

However, that's not possible since data has not been created yet, because data requires x:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([60, 95])
  .range([0, width]);

// Generate a histogram using twenty uniformly-spaced bins.
var data = d3.layout.histogram()
  .bins(x.ticks(7))
  (values);
```

So how can I use data to create x if x is needed to create data?

Note that scaling the large side of the histogram does work:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, Number(d3.max(values))])
  .range([0, width]);
```

However, if the small side is anything but zero, things break:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([Number(d3.min(values)), Number(d3.max(values))])
  .range([0, width]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you're computing the width of the bars is incorrect for your particular use case; in particular it results in negative widths (as the error message indicates). You need to take the width of the range and divide it by the number of items (minus a small number if you want gaps):

```
.attr("width", (x.range()[1] - x.range()[0]) / data.length - 2)
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x4374h66/1/).